# Backbone View property returning undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is my view:

```
define(
    [
        "jquery"
    ,   "underscore"    
    ,   "backbone"
    ,   "eventView"
    ]
,   function($, _, Backbone, EventView) {
        "use strict";

        var TimelineView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'div'
        ,   className: 'column'

        ,   _EventViews: {} // Cache event views for reuse

        ,   initialize: function() {
                this.collection.bind('add', this.add);
                this.collection.bind('reset', this.add);
            }

        ,   render: function() {
                return this;
            }

            // Listen for additions to collection and draw views
        ,   add: function(model) {
                var eventView = new EventView({
                    model: model
                });

                // Cache the event
                console.log(this._EventViews);
                this._EventViews[model.get('id')] = eventView;

                // Draw event
                eventView.render(); 
            }
        });

        return TimelineView
    }
);
```

As you can see I set the `_EventViews` property to contain an empty object. However when I call the `add()` function `console.log(this._EventViews)` returns undefined and the following statement fails.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that within `add`, `this` is not your TimelineView. See this article for an explanation of context in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

You can solve this in a few different ways. The easiest in this situation is to use the third parameter of `bind` or `on` (these two are the same).

```
initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('add', this.add, this);
            this.collection.on('reset', this.add, this);
        }
```

Or use `listenTo` instead.

```
initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.add);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.add);
        }
```

Also, your `_EventViews` cache will be shared by all instances of `TimelineView`.  If that is not what you want, create it in `initialize` instead.

```
initialize: function() {
            this._EventViews = {};
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.add);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.add);
        }
```

Comment: Just lacks an explanation of the problem imo, but right for both points.

Comment: Thanks, still trying to get into the mindset of Backbone and every tutorial seems to use a different structure but I'll go with `listenTo` and thanks for the heads up about `_EventViews` being static.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
<script>

var TimelineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div'
,   className: 'column'

,   _EventViews: {} // Cache event views for reuse

,   initialize: function() {
        //this.collection.bind('add', this.add);
        //this.collection.bind('reset', this.add);
    }

,   render: function() {
        return this;
    }

    // Listen for additions to collection and draw views
,   add: function(model) {
        var eventView = ({
            model: model
        });

        // Cache the event
        console.log(this._EventViews); // Prints: Object {}
        this._EventViews[model.get('id')] = eventView;

        // Draw event
        eventView.render();
    }
});

var a = new TimelineView();
a.add();

</script>
```

I think the problem is the `.add()` method is invoked from the collection `add` event. When you add a listener (with in backbone is done with the `.bind()` function) you must `bind` (on the native meaning) the function:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'add');
```

OR

```
this.add = this.add.bind(this);
```

You have to do it before you add the function as a listener:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'add');
    this.collection.bind('add', this.add);
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.add);
}
```

Comment: You identified the problem, but I completely disagree with your methods of binding the context. Either use the 3rd argument of the `bind` method (boilerplate) or the `listenTo` method introduced in the version 0.9.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I'll always prefeer the native funct.bind(context) ;)